# MySQL if statement subquery value

Tags: mysql, if-statement, subquery

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT IF((SELECT something FROM table) AS tmp) > 0, tmp, (SELECT bla FROM oter_table))
```

Unfortunately the 'as tmp' and returing the tmp is not working. How can I get this to work? without doing repeating the query:

```
SELECT IF((SELECT something FROM table) > 0, (SELECT something FROM table), (SELECT bla FROM oter_table))
```

Comment: Have you read up on the `JOIN` statement?

Comment: The actual situation is a bit more complicated, therefore I would like to know how I could fix the above situation (without joins).

Comment: Maybe don't use a RDBMS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`User-Defined Variables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html):

```
SELECT IF(
          @val:=(SELECT something FROM table1) > 0, 
          @val, 
          (SELECT bla FROM table2)
       )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a17d0/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF( (SELECT something AS tmp FROM first_table) > 0, tmp, (SELECT bla FROM other_table) )
```

**EDIT** This is not going to work. You need to quantify the selection somewhere with a "WHERE" clause, like so:

```
SELECT IF( (SELECT something FROM first_table) > 0, (SELECT something FROM first_table), (SELECT something_else FROM second_table) ) FROM first_table WHERE something = 45
```