# How to implement a PHP condition using pure SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have this tables structure:

```
// Posts
+----+------------+-----------------------+----------------+-------------+
| id |   title    |        content        |  money_amount  |  author_id  |
+----+------------+-----------------------+----------------+-------------+
| 1  | title 1    | content 1             | NULL           | 12345       |
| 2  | title 2    | content 2             | 25             | 42355       |
| 3  | title 3    | content 3             | 5              | 53462       |
| 4  | title 4    | content 4             | NULL           | 36346       |
| 5  | title 5    | content 5             | 15             | 13322       |
+----+------------+-----------------------+----------------+-------------+
//                                          ^^ NULL means this post is free


// Money
+---------+--------------+
| post_id | user_id_paid | 
+---------+--------------+
| 2       | 42355        |  // He is author of post
| 2       | 34632        |  // This row means besides author, this user 34632 can see this post too. Because he paid the money of this post.
| 3       | 53462        |  // He is author of post
| 5       | 13322        |  // He is author of post
| 3       | 73425        |  // This row means besides author, this user 34632 can see this post too. Because he paid the money of this post.
+---------|--------------+
```

**Note1:** All `post_id`(s) in the `Money` table are belong to those posts which are non-free.

**Note2:** Always there is a row belong to author of post *(which is non-free)* in the `Money` table.

**Note3:** `Money` table is just to determines who can see such a post.

---

Now this user `$_SESSION['current_user'] = '23421'` wants to see this post `id = 2`. Here is my code:

```
$stm = $this->dbh->prepare(SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE id = '2');
$stm->execute();
$result = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ( $result[money] == '') {   // money_amount is NULL in the Posts table
    this post is free and everybody can see it
} else {

    $stm = $this->dbh->prepare(SELECT count(1) FROM Money WHERE post_id = '2' and user_id = $_SESSION['current_user']);
    $num_rows = $stm->fetchColumn();

    if($num_rows){
        $paid = true;  // This means current user paid the cost of post and he can see it.
    } else {
        $paid = false; // this means current user didn't pay the cost of post and he cannot see it.
    }
}
```

I want to know, can I implement those two query in one query and do that condition using MySQL instead of PHP ?

Comment: @frz3993 Actually I need to check **if the value of `money_amount` column is not `NULL`** then `join` to `Money` table and check whether the id of current user is exists or not. How can I implement that condition using MySQL?

Comment: Try with this query, I've written it very fast i don't know if it's right. If the result is >0 the user can see the post. `SELECT count(*) FROM Money, Posts WHERE (Posts.id = 2 and Posts.money_amout is null) OR (Money.post_id = 2 and Money.user_id_paid = $_SESSION['current_user'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution using `IF` and `EXISTS` functions(MySql):

```
...
$stmt = $conn->prepare(" 
        SELECT IF(p.money_amount,1,0) as notfree, 
        EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `Money` WHERE `post_id` = ? AND`user_id_paid` = ?) as paid
        FROM `Posts` p WHERE p.id = ? ");

$stmt->execute([2, $_SESSION['current_user'], 2]);
$result = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!$result['notfree']) {  // post is free
    // this post is free and everybody can see it
} else {
    $paid = ($result['paid'])? true : false; 
}
```

Comment: as for subqueries within IF statement - consider the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723808/mysql-if-statement-subquery-value

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join, and the query below uses `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT * FROM Money
LEFT JOIN Posts ON Money.post_id = Posts.id
WHERE ((Posts.money_amount IS NOT NULL AND Money.user_id_paid = :userId)
      OR Posts.money_amount IS NULL) AND Posts.id = :postId
```

Note that `:userId` is a placeholder for `PDO` parameterized query, where you should bind the parameter to the placeholder before execution. Like:

```
$postId = 2;
$stmt->bindParam('userId', $_SESSION['current_user']);
$stmt->bindParam('postId', $postId);
```

Also note that when binding the placeholder name doesn't need the colon. Using a `RIGHT JOIN` means you `SELECT` from the `Posts` table and join the `Money` table.